# Как сделать диаграмму в форме половины доната?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, диаграммы, chart.js

Я пытаюсь построить диаграмму в форме половины бублика с необычным скруглением делений.

Дизайн выглядит следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решил использовать chart.js. Проект написан на vue 3, данные динамические.

В целом удалось повторить дизайн, но никак не получается скруглить боковые углы, в итоге имею вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код выглядит следующим образом:

```js
<template>
    <div class="doughnut">
        <canvas ref="chart"></canvas>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>

import {onMounted, ref} from "vue";
import {
    Chart,
    DoughnutController,
    ArcElement,
} from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/chart.js@4.2.1';
  
Chart.register(
    DoughnutController,
    ArcElement,
);

const chart = ref(null);
const data = {
    datasets: [
        {
            data: [33, 23, 8, 7],
            backgroundColor: [
                "#F04B92",
                "#54B2FD",
                "#FFC24B",
                "#49EBCE",
            ],
            display: true,
            offset: 0,
            spacing: -30,
            borderColor: "#fff",
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderRadius: {outerStart: 16,  outerEnd: 0, innerStart: 16},
            cutout: "58%",
        }
    ],
    labels: false
};

const config = {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data,
    options: {
        rotation: 270,
        circumference: 180,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        responsive: true,
        animation: {
            animateRotate: true
        },
    },
}
```

Так же вот тут есть полностью рабочий пример https://codepen.io/yurikssi/pen/yLGVBPm

Подскажите, как выполнить нужное скругление и в целом избавиться от зазоров между делениями? Возможно ли это сделать с помощью этого инструмента, или необходимо использовать что-то другое?

Comment: Это плохой дизайн, не  надо так делать.

Comment: @Эникейщик согласен, но не мне выбирать

Comment: А если добавить с краю 0% фонового цвета? По крайней мере, с одной стороны должно сработать.

Comment: если 0%, то он просто вообще не отображает эту секцию, а если больше, то уже смещает первую цветную секцию. Хотя скругление действительно появляется

Comment: Если элементы данного изображения можна выгрузить в векторе, то можете дернуть те края в `svg` потом через ::before ::after реализовать при помощи свойства - `clip-path` и `overflow:hidden;`  не сложно, но муторно. ПС Дизайн дырявый, не надо так делать.  Можете получить ещё проблем при мобильном отображении.